# How to run docker image in minikube

Tags: minikube, dockerhub

How to run docker hub image in minikube, seems like minikube doesn't connect to docker hub to download docker image by default.

Comment: check first `docker pull image` is working or not.

Comment: What exactly did you try? Did you get some errors?

Comment: I found my answer.

kubectl create deployment hello-node --image=hello-node:v1

Answer (score 0):

With image tag

```
kubectl create deployment hello-nginx --image=nginx
```